# OrientDB - SQL command to pass array value as parameter in OrientDB function

Tags: sql, function, parameters, orientdb

I have a simple sql query in orientdb function like this:

```
select * 
from TestExecutionPlanReport 
where executionPlan IN :executionPlans
```

It accepts "executionPlans" as parameter where an array value should be passed.

When I tried just one value like "#59:71", it works and return the wanted output. BUT when I tried to pass in an array value like "[#59:71,#59:214]", is not working. It returns an empty response. It works when I query "select * from SomeClass where field IN [#59:71,#59:214]" (Not in OrientDb function)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to run an SQL query from Scala code. I solved it by passing a set as the parameter instead of a list or an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you are trying to execute the query you've mentioned in a OrientDB server side function (probably written in JavaScript) which takes `executionPlan` as a parameter.

I also noticed this happening if you use parameterized queries. A parameterized query is something like the following;

`var query = "select * from TestExecutionPlanReport where executionPlan IN ?";
return db.query(query, executionPlans);`

However, when I used string concatenation to build the query, it works. I'm referring to the following

`var query = "select * from TestExecutionPlanReport where executionPlan IN " + executionPlans`

If you are using string concatenation I think the issue is with how you pass the parameter. Rather than passing `"[#59:71,#59:214]"`, try passing `[#59:71,#59:214]` to your function and see if it works.

Usually when you use string concatenation to build queries, you can use the `print()` function to print the concatenated query on the OrientDB console. However, concatenation based queries could be exploited to do SQL injections, hence discouraged.

I cannot explain why this doesn't work for parameterized queries. I'll do more research on this. Perhaps it's a bug. I'm using OrientDB 2.0.3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No im not trying to do the execution in JAVASCRIPT. Its in SQL. That is the real issue. Thanks for stopping by

Comment: What you've mentioned should work in SQL as well. Your question is not clear.